# Node JS Restream ts url

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, stream, video-streaming

everyone. I hope you're all doing well.

I'm trying to read data from a TS stream link and rebroadcast it through Node.js. I'm not sure if this is possible. I want the connection to be one, meaning that when 10 users connect to my site to watch the stream, my server makes a single connection to the site that provides the stream link and distributes the same data to the users. I hope no one gets upset because I have no idea at all about how to deal with video and streaming. This is just the beginning of understanding how things work, so I don't know if this is possible in Node.js or any other language.

```
const https = require('https');
const streamUrl = 'https://www.example.com/path/to/stream.ts'; // ts or any ... 

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    https.get(streamUrl , (stream) => {
        stream.pipe(res);
    });
});
```

I have done some research in a few articles, and they mention that it is necessary to use a package like gstream or ffmpeg. I hope that someone can guide us, or perhaps it's a simple matter of making some adjustments to the code. The truth is, I am lost.